# Using WP_Query and WP_Meta_Query Outside of Wordpress

Tags: wp-query, mysql, meta-query, cron

I'm trying to figure out how I can utilize WP_Query and WP_Meta_Query outside of the WordPress install, for server Cron jobs.

I've tried including `wp-load.php` but this also brings in plugins like WooCommerce into the mix and I'm getting all kinds of header warnings, etc. I just need to be interacting with the database, not all of the theme and plugin methods.

This is an example of the warnings that I currently get:

```
Notice: wp_woocommerce_session_d34eac23ade02d0820a9089e923eed79 cookie cannot be set - headers already sent by /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/dev.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/woo-product-slider/main.php on line 214 in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/dev.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php on line 733

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_query_var() (previously declared in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/dev.mywebsite.com/wp-includes/query.php:26) in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/dev.mywebsite.com/wp-includes/query.php on line 29
```

Comment: It sounds like you're including `wp_head()` as well. Could you post the rest of the code that contains your `wp-load.php` include?

Comment: `wp_head()` is not included... at least not that I know of. The only thing that is being used is `wp-load.php`

Comment: Is wp_load.php at the very top of the file? There shouldn't be anything before it.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

```
require_once 'wp-config.php';
global $wpdb;
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );
$Query= new WP_Query($args);
```

You can use similar way to achieve what you want.